# Class design best way to handle multi-value options and the selected value?

Tags: c#, class, drop-down-menu, interface

What's the best way to design a class (or classes) that can hold the potential values of item, as well as the one the user actually selected? I've come across this problem before and always feel like I'm missing a core class design feature.

Right now I usually do something like the following

```
class MultiChoice
    Name (I.e. Box Size)
    Default Value ("22x15")
    PotentialValues ({"10x10","20x20","22x15"})
```

But that doesn't handle the actual value the user selected, so I add that in.

```
class MultiChoice
    Name (I.e. Box Size)
    Default Value ("22x15")
    PotentialValues ({"10x10","20x20","22x15"})
    SelectedValue
```

That doesn't feel right though, because when I construct a drop-down I'm filling in stuff with `SelectedValue = null`.  Then when I store the data, I'm storing all the options too, which I don't need.

Is there a better way to handle this with an interface or other language construct?  I always feel like I'm missing something blatantly obvious here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because design level questions belong on Programmers.

Comment: Come spend the effort to write some real code that will at least compile.  What is forcing you store the all the options when you store the data?  What is wrong with using the Default Value for initial SelectedValue?

Comment: Sorry, I'm still new to questions.  How do I submit this to Programmers?  As for writing code, I haven't written any because I'm still designing on paper. I certainly could write the whole class in C# and post it here, but that just seems to clutter up the question, in my opinion.

Comment: @user2283020 You submit the question to programmers in exactly the same way you submitted it here, you go to the site, click "ask a quesiton", and then ask your question.

Comment: @Servy when recommending other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 0):

You really have two separate entities here:

- MultiChoiceQuestion
- MultiChoiceAnswer

Create two separate classes to represent these two separate concepts.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC has the [SelectList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx) class.    While you might not actually be working in ASP.NET MVC, it seems clear that Microsoft felt that the concept of "backing class for a dropdown" was universal enough to warrant its own class.

In whatever you consider the "Model" (that part of your program containing the business domain classes and business logic), there will always exist database tables that serve as lookups for these dropdowns.

```
tblCountries
     CountryID     PK
     CountryCode   string
     FullName      string
```

In your ViewModel, there will be a corresponding list of countries from which you can populate the dropdown:

```
public class InvoiceViewModel
{
    ...
    public int CountryID { get; set; }

    public SelectList Countries { get; set; }
    // or
    public List<Country> Countries { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Of course, by the time you get to the UI, the actual dropdown contains enough plumbing to hold both the select list and the selected value.

Answer (score 0):

You really only need a single `Value` field. Set it to whatever you want in the constructor (so it's defaulted when the object is created). You can also change your 'potential values' to be static, so it's the same for the entire class.

```
public class Box
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public static List<string> AllowedValues { get; private set; }

        public Box()
        {
            AllowedValues.AddRange(new string[]{"10x10","20x20","22x15"});
            Value = AllowedValues.First();
        }
    }
```

Then when a user changes the value, simply update it.

```
Box thisBox = new Box();
string val = "22x15";
if (Box.AllowedValues.Contains(val))
    thisBox.Value = val;
```